# How to flatten or stringify an object (esp. Match)?

Tags: raku

How do we flatten or stringify Match (or else) object to be string data type (esp. in multitude ie. as array elements)? e.g.

```
'foobar' ~~ m{ (foo) };
say $0.WHAT;

my $foo = $0;
say $foo.WHAT
```

```
(Match)
(Match)
```

How to end up with `(Str)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just treat the objects as if they were strings.

If you apply a string operation to a value/object Raku will almost always just automatically coerce it to a string.

String operations include functions such as `print` and `put`, operators such as infix `eq` and `~` concatenation, methods such as `.starts-with` or `.chop`, interpolation such as "A string containing a `$variable`", and dedicated coercers such as `.Str` and `Str(...)`.

A `Match` object contains an overall match. Any "children" (sub-matches) are just captures of substrings of that overall match. So there's no need to flatten anything because you can just deal with the single overall match.

A list of `Match` objects is a list. And a list is itself an object. If you apply a string operation to a list, you get the elements of the list stringified with a space between each element.

So:

```
'foobar' ~~ m{ (f) (o) (o) };
put $/;          # foo
put $/ eq 'foo'; # True
put $/ ~ 'bar';  # foobar
put $/ .chop;    # fo
put "[$/]";      # [foo]
put $/ .Str;     # foo

my Str() $foo = $/;
say $foo.WHAT;   # (Str)

put 'foofoo' ~~ m:g{ (f) (o) (o) }; # foo foo
```

Answer (score 6):

[`~` is the `Str` contextualizer](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts#String):

```
'foobar' ~~ m{ (foo) };
say ~$0
```

will directly coerce it to a `Str`. You can use that if you have many matches, i. e.:

```
'foobar' ~~ m{ (f)(o)(o) };
say $/.map: ~*; # (f o o)
```

Answer (score 5):

The constructor for [`Str`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str) takes any [`Cool`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Cool) value as argument, including a regex [`Match`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match) object.

```
'foobar' ~~ m{ (foo) };
say $0.WHAT; # (Match)
say $0.Str.WHAT; # (Str)
```